# Is a dll to receive windows messages possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-messages

I'm working on a unity3d application and I need to be able to drag and drop files on it while running. Apparently this is not possible because the built `.exe` can't receive messages from Windows, such as `wm_dropfile` (which I need in this particular case).

I know that it is possible to add native code and dll's to unity, but I'm not sure whether receiving windows messages would be.

So far I have tweaked some C code to create a window that accepts files, but still have to create a dll and check if it works with unity at all.

Any knowledge or opinions on this? Have anyone tried this before?

Comment: This is not possible. Maybe with heavy hacking (e.g. with hooking (subclassing) & data injection) but I wouldn't recommend that. You should find a workaround, i.e. another way to read the file run-time (file open dialog?).

Comment: Well, in UWP builds you can hook up events between Unity and native code through VS2015. I can't really comment too much on it, but it's a possible alternative.